# Using a bat file to create a log

Tags: dll, batch-file

I am trying to monitor the install of software on our servers remotly with a script by checking the .dll file version. I am not sure if this can be done but after the install on all of the servers I would like to run a bat file to look at all of the servers and create a log file with the server name and that .dll file version number. Suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: How about a little more specific information?

Comment: I have a .dll file that is updated when the software is updated. I would like to be able to look at this file and write a compiled log file showing all of our servers and what version of the file they have. I was thinking of using a bat file but am not familiar enough with writign them to know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

First download STRINGS.EXE from here (to handle unicode).
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx

Here is a little something I have been using for quite a while.  It does a bit more than you asked for but maybe someone else would prefer to have all of this.  You can easily delete the parts you don't want. Add/remove file types as you like and remove the output sections you don't want.  It does not do exactly what you asked but the hard part is done and you can adapt as you see fit.  Save the code as FileVersions.bat (or whatever).  Put this bat file and the downloaded STRINGS.EXE in the same folder.  Execute this bat file to get output in FileVersions.txt (or whatever you name bat file).  It will look something like this.  Gets versions for all specified file types in folders underneath the current folder.  Get this modified as you desire and then handle multiple machines as you see fit.

====== Output ============
Versions for *.dll *.ocx *.exe files - Thu 08/08/2013 21:13:28.17

```
File=C:\Drivers\storage\strings.exe
FileDesc=strings
FileVer=2.41
ProductName=Sysinternals Strings
ProductVer=2.41

File=C:\Drivers\storage\R159108\TEACico2.dll
FileDesc=TEACico2.DLL
FileVer=1, 1, 0, 0
ProductName= TEACico2 DLL
ProductVer=1, 1, 0, 0
```

====== End of Output ============

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE %~n0
PUSHD %~dp0
SET FileTypes=*.dll *.ocx *.exe
SET OutFile=%~n0.txt
IF EXIST %OutFile% DEL /q %OutFile%
ECHO.Retrieving file versions for %FileTypes% files
ECHO.
ECHO.Versions for %FileTypes% files - %Date% %Time% > %OutFile%
ECHO.
FOR /R "%CD%" %%A IN (%FileTypes%) DO ECHO.%%A & CALL :FileVersion "%%A" >> %OutFile%
ECHO.
ECHO.Results are in %OutFile%
pause
GOTO :eof

REM ========================= Subroutines =========================
:FileVersion
SETLOCAL
ECHO.
ECHO.File=%~1

SET LineNum=Invalid
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN ('STRINGS %1 ^| FIND /N /V "" ^|  FIND /I "FileDescription"') DO SET LineNum=%%A
IF %LineNum%==Invalid GOTO :FileVer
SET /A LineNum += 1
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%A IN ('STRINGS %1 ^| FIND /N /V "" ^| FIND "[%LineNum%]"') DO SET FileDesc=%%B
IF NOT "%FileDesc%"=="FileVersion" SET FileDesc

:FileVer
SET LineNum=Invalid
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN ('STRINGS %1 ^| FIND /N /V "" ^| FIND /I "FileVersion"') DO SET LineNum=%%A
IF %LineNum%==Invalid GOTO :ProductName
SET /A LineNum += 1
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%A IN ('STRINGS %1 ^| FIND /N /V "" ^| FIND "[%LineNum%]"') DO SET FileVer=%%B
SET FileVer

:ProductName
SET LineNum=Invalid
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN ('STRINGS %1 ^| FIND /N /V "" ^| FIND /I "ProductName"') DO SET LineNum=%%A
IF %LineNum%==Invalid GOTO :ProductVer
SET /A LineNum += 1
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%A IN ('STRINGS %1 ^| FIND /N /V "" ^| FIND "[%LineNum%]"') DO SET ProductName=%%B
IF NOT "%ProductName%"=="ProductVersion" SET ProductName

:ProductVer
SET LineNum=Invalid
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%A IN ('STRINGS %1 ^| FIND /N /V "" ^| FIND /I "ProductVersion"') DO SET LineNum=%%A
IF %LineNum%==Invalid GOTO :Done
SET /A LineNum += 1
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%A IN ('STRINGS %1 ^| FIND /N /V "" ^| FIND "[%LineNum%]"') DO SET ProductVer=%%B
SET ProductVer

:Done
ENDLOCAL
GOTO:EOF
```